# Recommendation for algebraic number theory books beyond a basic introduction

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I have studied some basic algebraic number theory, including Dedekind theory, valuation theory, and a little local fields. Now I am thinking to study more and deeper, and hoping to study class field theory, so please help me which book should I choose?

The teacher told me that I should read Lang's or Neukirch's, but I don't know which is better and to choose, or if there is a better one?

Comment: Not an expert, but I thought I'd add a perhaps non-standard suggestion as a comment: Fermat's Last Theorem, by Edwards, is a historical account of the birth of the algebraic tools involved in attacking FLT, including I believe the ideal class group (related to class field theory?). To be clear, it is an algebraic number theory textbook, not just a history book.

Comment: What books have you already read, if at least partially?

Comment: I have tried to improve the title a little, but it is still quite general. Feel free to edit it to make it more precise - perhaps by making mention of class field theory. I was hesitant to do so myself.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about your books, but [Artin's](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Artin-Algebra-2nd-Edition/9780132413770.html) book is thought to be a good preparation.

Answer (score 2):

There is also Weil's *Basic Number Theory*, Cassels-Fröhlich *Algebraic Number Theory*, Serre's *Local Fields* and the lecture notes http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/index.html of James Milne.